# TinyMCE content removed when submitting form

Tags: javascript, spring, tinymce

I am using self hosted TinyMCE (5.2.0) as an editor for users to input rich text into our java application. The TinyMCE editor is initiated on the frontend in javascript and is converting a textarea in my form via the selector option as shown below.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#textareaEltId',
    plugins: "advlist autoresize autolink lists table paste",
    menubar: "edit insert format table tools",
    toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | bullist numlist',
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    contextmenu: false,
    paste_data_images: true
});
```

The contents of textarea are mapped to a string in a Spring ModelAttribute when the form is submitted. I've run into the issue that when a user submits the form when it contains a very specific substring, the substring (and the entire <p> and <span> that contain it) are removed entirely and only the remaining text is found in the ModelAttribute.

The majority of the time there is no issue, but I was able to narrow down a specific use case that reproduces the error every time:

The contents of the tinymce textarea when submitting the form:

```
<p><span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif;">test text</span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif;">s on</span></p>
```

and the contents of the ModelAttribute after submitting the form:

```
<p><span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif;">test text</span></p>
```

The "s on" in the second <p> is the portion that is getting removed, and I've found that any string that includes that substring will still be removed. I've also found that changing the test text element from <p><span>test text</span></p> to <p>test text</p>" also resolves the issue. Any other case and the contents of the ModelAttribute after submitting the form are exactly as I expect.

I've attempted changing TinyMCE versions and options, including the following:

- Upgrading to later versions of TinyMCE, both 5.10.7 and 6.7.0
- Various combinations of valid_elements, extended_valid_elements, valid_children to prevent the removal of <span>, including a blanket valid_elements: '*[*]'
- Testing this scenario with other TinyMCE editors/forms/ModelAttributes in the application
- Removing all current plugins and options
- Calling tinymce.activeEditor.triggerSave() in the form's onsubmit function

All of these attempts have resulted in the same problem.